# JavaFX change 3 slidebars' value to automatically update the rgb color

Tags: java, javafx

Set 3 slidebar: value from 0 to 255, 3 slidebar set as red, green and blue. I try to bind 3 slidebars to color and it's faild. So how can I solve this? When I change the slidebar, the color can change? How can I program this function? Thanks.

code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private Slider redbar;

    @FXML
    private Slider greenbar;

    @FXML
    private Slider bluebar;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        Integer redValue=(int)redbar.getValue();
        Integer greenValue=(int)greenbar.getValue();
        Integer blueValue=(int)bluebar.getValue();
        Color col=Color.rgb(redValue,greenValue,blueValue);//I only can set as like this, then pass color to laber
        // I wanner bind col with laber.backgroundProperty() here
    }
```

Comment: post your code please. We can't just guess what your program looks like

Comment: See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Using `getValue()` will give you the value at current time. If you want to react to changes you will need to attach a listener to the corresponding [property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#valueProperty):

```
   ChangeListener myListener = new ChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void changed(...) {
           // Collect current values and set rgb color
   }

   ...

   redValue.valueProperty().addListener(myListener);
   greenValue.valueProperty().addListener(myListener);
   blueValue.valueProperty().addListener(myListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you wrote you want to bind the value. What you're doing in your code is not binding at all however. You simply retrieve the value just after the fxml has been loaded before the scene is even rendered.

Instead you need to create a binding depending on the slider values:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    label.backgroundProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb((int) redbar.getValue(),
                                                                                                                   (int) greenbar.getValue(),
                                                                                                                   (int) bluebar.getValue()),
                                                                                                         CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                                                                                                         Insets.EMPTY)),
                                                                 redbar.valueProperty(),
                                                                 greenbar.valueProperty(),
                                                                 bluebar.valueProperty()));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it works. Thanks. However, when I try to bind with rgb(int,int,int,bouble), it doesn't work. I change the code just add a opacity scrollbar,add code:  { (int) opacitybar.getValue()),  and also opacitybar.valueProperty()}       it's failed.      I checked API:    Color c = Color.rgb(0,0,255,1.0); //use 0->255 integers, explicit alpha of 1.0 .        It allows this. I don't know how to bind this, could you help ?

Comment: @A.Sheh If you cast the double to `int` you loose information, since you're casting to a integral type. In this case you'll either get opacity 1 or opacity 0. Simply don't cast the value in this case, since the source and target types are both `double`.

Comment: Much thanks,Fabian. I add code: { opacitybar.getValue()), and also opacitybar.valueProperty()}  and now I made it. the opacitybar works. thanks a lot.